# If the limit of the sum exists, then the limit of each component exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider two sequences $\{b_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. Suppose that
$$
(*) \hspace{1cm} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n+a_n)=L<\infty
$$

Does this imply
$$
\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n \text{ and it is finite}
$$
$$
\exists \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \text{ and it is finite}
$$
so that (*) is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=-\lim_{n\rightarrow i\infty} a_n+L
$$
?

Comment: (Real sequences) For any $b_n$, the sequence $b_n + (-b_n)$ is constant, regardless of whether $b_n$ is convergent or not. You can deduce the answer to your question from this observation.

Comment: No. Consider e.g. the sequences $a_n=(-1)^n$, $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: It would probably improve the title to say "summand" rather than "component" as more precise terminology (matching the use of "sum").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. E.g let $a_n=n$ and $b_n=-n$.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be true in general, but it is always true if the two sequecences are monotonic and with constant sign.

Comment: Thanks: (i) monotonic in the same direction ? (ii) with the same sign?

Comment: @CGT I think that same sign suffices! But it should be proved.